# Jade dynamic 'template=content 'meaning

Tags: html, meteor, pug, meteor-blaze

I have a jade template layout.jade file from wekan:

```
...
template(name="userFormsLayout")
  section.auth-layout
  //-h1.at-form-landing-logo
     img(src="{{pathFor '/wekan-logo.png'}}" alt="Wekan")
  section.auth-dialog
    +Template.dynamic(template=content)
    div.at-form-lang
...
```

i dont understand what exactly this line is doing:

```
+Template.dynamic(template=content)
```

Can somebody explain it to me, i am most curious about this content reference.

Comment: Not an expert on jade, but looks like it's an include, where content is a variable containing an html template (or a url to an html template)

Comment: @fatman i also think so but i don't find any references to it, so i was hoping for a little bit more detail on this portal to this issue

Answer (score 1):

It's no related to jade syntax but to Blaze, see related documentation [here](http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Template-dynamic).

An example of use: when you use a router, you can define what template name is the `content` dynamic template for each route. Here you are an example with FlowRouter (`coffeescript` syntax)

```
...
FlowRouter.route '/home',
    name: 'home'
    action: ->
        BlazeLayout.render 'layout',
            content: 'contentTemplateNameForHomeRoute'


FlowRouter.route '/user_profile',
    name: 'userProfile'
    action: ->
        BlazeLayout.render 'layout',
            content: 'contentTemplateNameForUserProfileRoute'
...
```

This could be your layout template (`jade`syntax)

```
template(name='layout')
  +header
  +Template.dynamic template ='content'
...
```